# Program Not Outputting Correctly Depending on Standard Input

Tags: c++

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. reads a token stream from standard input(using token oriented input)
2. picking out zipcodes which are assumed to be 5 character strings preceded by the token "zip:".
3. The program prints the top 10 most frequently occuring zipcodes and their frequency, in descending order of frequency.

My code seems to be compiling correctly when my standard input looks like : zip:22333 zip:23423 zip:22333  etc.

However we were given some sample code it's supposed to work for

```
    city: Sherwood Park zip: T8C 1C3 $20.00 <87.3197428190@982662399.XmT.srvr@n325.xnot.com> cc: visa addr: 4811-100 Prudential Drive     =4=Z city: Toronto zip: M1P 4V4 $25.00    
<8708.37428190@62986095171.XmT.srvr@n325.xnot.com> cc: visa addr: Box 484 =4=Z city: Clyde zip: T0G 0P0 $20.00 <8869.37428190@62987268014.XmT.srvr@n326.xnot.com> cc: visa addr: 490 E. Madison St.  =4=Z 3220 Hunt House
```

When using the sample code, instead of the output displaying the zips in decending order of frequency with their frequency becides them, I get 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (indicating a count of 3 for some reason and then no other counts).

I know there is a discrepancy between the directions and the file zip codes, namely that the files are stored like zip: 39450 with a whitespace between zip and the number.  How do I modify the inside of while(!cin.fail()) to account for this and count the zipcode one white space away from "zip: " using token oriented input? Note there are some non-US zipcodes we are not supposed to count.

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0, n=0, l=0, c=0, temp2, flag=1;
    string zipsstring, zipsstringf, temp1;
    string stringarray[10000];
    int countarray[10000]={0};
    cin >> zipsstring;
    while(cin.get() && !cin.fail())
    {
        if(zipsstring.find("zip:", n != std::string::npos))
        { 
            zipsstringf=zipsstring.substr(4, 5);
            for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
            {
                if(stringarray[i]==zipsstringf)
                {
                    countarray[i]+=1;
                    c=1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(c==0)
            {
                stringarray[n]=zipsstringf;
                countarray[n]+=1;
                n++;
            }


        }
        cin >> zipsstring;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n && flag; i++)
    {
        flag=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++){
            if(countarray[j+1]>countarray[j])
            {
                temp1=stringarray[j];
                temp2=countarray[j];
                stringarray[j]=stringarray[j+1];
                countarray[j]=countarray[j+1];
                stringarray[j+1]=temp1;
                countarray[j+1]=temp2;
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        cout << stringarray[x] << " " << countarray[x] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for real use (rather than a homework assignment where use of the right tools is prohibited) I'd use a regex library to do the job:

```
std::regex w("[Zz]ip:[ \t\n]*[0-9]{5}");
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {

    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), w),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Of course, with this it becomes fairly obvious that what you're doing is basically nothing more than a specific invocation of `grep`, but such is life sometimes.